# SORT to replace a column in JCL

Tags: mainframe, zos, jcl

Do you know a command to sort a file to replace a column with the same value in all the rows?

For example, I want to generate a new file with the same order as the original, except at the column 66 to 68, I want to put XX in all the rows.

Note: the row may have BINARY characters in some columns.

Comment: Have a look at the outrec option https://www.google.com.au/search?q=sort+outrec&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=nHzLVuLyA6TImAXVw7bADQ (also inrec could be used if you do not need to sort on the field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Founded, never mind

```
//SYSIN    DD *
           SORT FIELDS=COPY
           OUTREC OVERLAY=(105:C'XXXXXX')
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11366641)

Comment: @wogsland it is a full answer. "How do I overlay a value in a record?" - use OVERLAY. It is difficult to expand upon. It would be better to close the question, but what reason would fit?